# Having unknown error with Getters and Setters

Tags: java, class, variables, setter, getter

I have some code that is utilising a variable from one class to another,  I am using getters and setters and I checked that when i setClassName() before changing class that it works but i can't acces it properly from the other class, it return's null.

http://pastebin.com/6AP4c6ii -- CLASS A

http://pastebin.com/QCnWDnYs -- CLASS B

There is more code but it's relatively messy and long, im a noob to this and am working on ways to improve my coding and this is just a little project.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Most likely it is empty String i.e. "" if you don't see any printout.

Comment: @Braj In that case it would print `null` which the OP claims it doesn't. I am more included to believe the debug message than what the OP believe the program should do. esp if they haven't tried to debug their program with a debugger.

Comment: Show us more of your code.  There isn't enough info here for us to help.

Comment: Okay, will upload the full code of both classes to pastebin

Comment: If code is long and messy then create and post [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/). There is also high chance that you will find cause of your problem yourself while creating it.

Comment: 'There is more code but it's relatively messy and long, im a noob'


You were warned, anyway i figured out my issue, i was instantiating my class and that meant the variables weren't being carried through to the next class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns null because you actually never set the variable.

```
CLASSA Ccs = new CLASSA(gsm);
@Override
public void init() {
    getFirstCompanion();

    getVariables();

}

private void getVariables() {
    classChoice = Ccs.getClassChoice();

    System.out.println("Init, class is " + classChoice); //here, this returns as nothing, not     null, nothing

}
```

You see, you are creating a totally new object when declaring `new CLASSA(gsm)`, any changes you made to a previous object is not reflected, because this a **fresh new object**, therefore its **chosenClass** attribute, is initialized to **null**. Since you are getting the value without previously setting it, you are getting a **null value**

I hope I made myself clear enough, and I hope I helped you!

### Edit

If you want to share the same variable across multiple instances, you can make them `static`:

```
private static String chosenClass = "";

public static void setChosenClass(String chosenClass)
{
       this.chosenClass= chosenClass;
}

public static String getChosenClass()
{
       return chosenClass;
}
```

Comment: Actually this helps a lot, i realise the way i am doing this is creating a new instantiation, is there no way for me to carry over my variables using the same method then? I could make a new class but i'm new, there could be better ways.

Comment: You can always use static variables, which is not preferable, but they can be shared across multiple instances. You set them anywhere, and you can access them anywhere. You need to change the variable declaration to `public static`, as well as the getters and setters

Comment: I'm editing my answer and posting an example of this

Comment: Yeah i understand static variables, i was told by a few people on here and my Computer Science teacher they were almost a last resort, thank you very much though, if i could upvote you i would.

Answer (score 0):

Does "my code to go to the next class" mean you instantiate class B? Because then Class B might have another instance of A then the one you set the class choice on.

Comment: Yes i believe it does, do you see anyway that i could still use this method while carrying over variables?